# How to check whether child method called super or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Parent
  def a_method
    # some crucial work has to run for every child class
  end
end
# Example 1
class Child < Parent
  def a_method
    super
  end
end

# Example 2
class Child < Parent
  def a_method
  end
end
```

I want to raise an error in case of Example 2
that `super` must be called on overridden method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want raise an error in case of Example 2 that super must be called on overridden method

It's a wrong tool for the job. You can't dictate children what to do. This is better done with some OO design. If some work *has* to be done always, then don't suggest child classes to override the method. Instead, override only the "custom" part. Example:

```
class Parent
  def a_method
    crucial_work do
      custom_handling
    end
  end

  # child classes override this one, not a_method
  def custom_handling
    # no-op
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def custom_handling
    "doing custom handling here"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Sergio Tulentsev, It is helpful. But currently I am using `composite design pattern` for the job. And I just wanted to know how to force the child object to call super(As we do in JAVA). I found there is no way.

Comment: @AravindVemula: yes, ruby is much more allowing.